# Block all Wednesdays and Thursdays while inserting dates into MySql table

Tags: c#, mysql

With the below code I can insert a range of dates into the MySql table, but I need to restrict dates based on Weekdays.
For example I want to restrict all dates from entering the table which are Wednesdays.

```
protected void Submit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DateTime startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtstartdate.Text);
DateTime enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtenddate.Text);
for (DateTime date = startdate; date <= enddate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    try
    {
        var shtdate = date.ToShortDateString();
        string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mydb;UID=myid;PASSWORD=abc123;";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        string cmdText = "INSERT INTO approved(agentlogin ,leavetype ,date ,time, reason)VALUES ( @login, @type, @date, 'Full day', @reason)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", Label1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", ddlleavetype.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", shtdate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reason", txtreason.Text);

        connection.Open();

        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();

        //lblError.Text = "Data Saved";

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.Write("not entered");
        //lblError.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
}
```

So how can I go about it? Thanks for any help

Comment: MySQL does not enforce check constraints.  So, I think you would have to implement this either with a trigger, or just check those dates in your C# code before inserting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making conditions based on the 2 weekdays Wednesday and Thursday, I wrote the conditions based on all the other 5 days as shown below.

```
protected void Submit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtstartdate.Text);
    DateTime enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtenddate.Text);
    for (DateTime date = startdate; date <= enddate; date = date.AddDays(1))
    {
         if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
         {
              var shtdate = date.ToShortDateString();
              string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mydb;UID=myid;PASSWORD=abc123;";
              MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
              string cmdText = "INSERT INTO approved(agentlogin ,leavetype ,date ,time, reason)VALUES ( @login, @type, @date, 'Full day', @reason)";
              MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", Label1.Text);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", ddlleavetype.Text);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", shtdate);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reason", txtreason.Text);
              connection.Open();
              int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         else{ 
         }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `DateTime.DayOfWeek` to skip all dates which has `DayOfWeek.Wednesday` or `DayOfWeek.Thursday` like this:

```
for (DateTime date = startdate; date <= enddate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
    {
        // skip to next day
        continue;
    }

    try 
    {
        // write to database
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.Write("not entered");
        //lblError.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know I can use DayOfWeek but the problem is skipping the date. How can I go about it?

Comment: Your objective is *restrict all dates from entering the table for certain weekday*. I know that MySQL has built-in `DAYOFWEEK()` function to deal with weekdays, but I think seems easier to implement in C# code.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime has a DayOfWeek property. (check it out [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx)).

You can just use it inside an if statement and you're good to go.