# Disable custom days on jQuery UI Datepicker and asp.net calendar

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to block days on jQuery datepicker and also for asp calendar, For example the label value is "Sat,Sun" and so I wanna block all Saturdays and Sundays

```
<asp:Label ID="lblweekoff" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Orange">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdate" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" CssClass="datepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I tried using if else condition to achieve this, but its not working,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function jScript() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
         var lblweekoff = document.getElementById("lblweekoff");
            if (lblweekoff.value == "Sat,Sun") {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                    minDate: 0,
                    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    maxDate: 2020,
                    yearRange: '2018:+' + new Date().getFullYear().toString(),
                    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    var day = date.getDay();
                    return [(day != 0 && day != 6)];
                    }

                });
            }
            else {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                    minDate: 0,
                    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    maxDate: 2020,
                    yearRange: '2018:+' + new Date().getFullYear().toString()


                });
            }
   } 
</script>
```

Comment: nope, I want to do it based on Label text only. But he gives different ideas

Comment: @ershoaib it is either block weekends or week days but i want to do it with if else conditions based on the label text, if the label shows Mon,Tue it should block Monday and Tuesday, do you have chime? I can share my screen with you so you can get better idea

Comment: means you label has `Sat,Sun` then those days must be disabled like for `Mon, Tue` and so on... right?

Comment: @ershoaib yep you're right. You already might have an idea of what kind of project I'm working on right? it is a leave planner, So I need to block their week-offs

Comment: @ershoaib ok and also if it is possible to do from server side please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable some week days in jQuery Datepicker or asp:Calendar like `Sun` or `Mon` or any else from week

OR

combinations of weekdays like `Sun,Mon` or `Tue,Wed,Thu` or any else from week then

Just take code inside `setDays` function and put it where you want.

**1) `jQuery UI Datepicker`**

```js
var selecteddays = '';  //<= var lblweekoff = document.getElementById("lblweekoff");

        function setDays(days) {
            selecteddays = days;

            $(function () {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                    inline: true,
                    beforeShowDay: highlightDays,

                });
            });

            function highlightDays(date) {

                var days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
                var d = new Date(date);
                var dayName = days[d.getDay()];

                var selectedSplittedDays = selecteddays.split(',');

                for (var i = 0; i < selectedSplittedDays.length; i++) {

                    if (selectedSplittedDays[i] == dayName) {
                        return [false];
                    }
                }
                return [true];

            }
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" onclick="setDays('Sun,Mon')" value="Sun,Mon" />Sun,Mon <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" onclick="setDays('Mon,Tue')" value="Mon,Tue" />Mon,Tue <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" onclick="setDays('Tue,Wed')" value="Tue,Wed" />Tue,Wed <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" onclick="setDays('Wed,Thu')" value="Wed,Thu" />Wed,Thu <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" onclick="setDays('Thu,Fri')" value="Thu,Fri" />Thu,Fri <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" onclick="setDays('Fri,Sat')" value="Fri,Sat" />Fri,Sat <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" onclick="setDays('Sat,Sun')" value="Sat,Sun" />Sat,Sun <br />
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
        Date:
        <input class="datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker" data-weekends="true">
    </div>
```

**2) `asp:Calendar`**

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    }

    //Same for other days
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can try adding onLoad function on label because the label fetches the text from mysql table on page load, still trying to figure out how

Comment: after you successfully fetch the values in label then bind those values to `selecteddays` in javascript variable

Comment: Is it possible to do dayrender on server side for datepickers? If there is could you please let me know?

Comment: means do you want to disable dates on jquery datepicker from serve side?

Comment: yes thats what I want to do if possible. Is it even possible?

Comment: you are not able to get days in database to asp label. bcoz you are already did that

Comment: Yep and trying to figure out how to bind the valu to selecteddays in javascript. I tried to get it by ID but it doesn't work.

Comment: just fetch your days by using sql query and bind it to label

Comment: Hi, can we connect now?

Answer (score -1):

A `<label>` has no `value`.

Personally I would put a data attribute on the input and use `each()` even if you only have one datepicker so you can access the element before initiating the plugin

```js
$('.datepicker').each(function() {
  var $input = $(this);
  var showWeekends = $input.data('weekends');

  $input.datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var day = date.getDay();
      return [showWeekends || ![0, 6].includes(day)];
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date1 (allow weekends):
  <input class="datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker" data-weekends="true">
</p>
<p>Date2 (no weekends):
  <input class="datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker" data-weekends="false">
</p>
```

Comment: Its not about blocking weekends, The label text may differ based on the value fetched from database and so it might Mon,Tue or any 2 weekdays. So I need to block the weekdays based on the text displayed on table.

Comment: If you mean block all weekdays reverse the logic. Could also pass array into data attribute. Not entirely clear what all your filter criteria are. You only mentioned the weekend days

Comment: I might have to block any two days of the 7 weekdays depending on the label text. It might be Mon,Tue or Tue,Wed or Wed,Thu or Thu,Fri, or Fri,Sat or Sat,Sun or Sun,Mon. The label text would be one of any of these 7 combinations.

Comment: Ok can do `data-block="[1,4]"` and jQuery data() will read that as array so you can see if day is in that array. Would be cleanest and you can easily get the day indexing server side to do it. I actually started creating this answer that way then thought it was overkill thinking all you wanted was to toggle weekends

Comment: But I need to know how I can do it based on label text

Comment: Why can't you parse the text server side into the numbers array? You need to convert that text into a day index somewhere...might just as well do it server side. I'm also guessing you might be working with DateTime objects there to create the text perhaps?

Comment: Yeah on the back end I wrote logic to avoid the dates from getting into the mysql table as shown in the below link. But I need to block the dates on the datepicker itself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762944/block-all-wednesdays-and-thursdays-while-inserting-dates-into-mysql-table

Comment: So it's not hard to get day index. Even if it's string like "Sun" a simple look up array would get what you need. If you do it from label text that's what you would need to do.

Comment: Are you actually storing datetime in mysql? If so just look up DateTime method for getting day index

Comment: In Mysql the table has column name date varchar()

Comment: Ok and is stored as day name text?

Comment: in javascript would be as simple as `var days =['Sun','Mon','Tue...]; console.log(days.indexOf('Mon'))`

Comment: nope I have another column week-off from a different table employee details.

Comment: the label shows the week-off of employees Selected from a different table. It is done on page_load.

Comment: What do you use to print the label text????????? Right there you can get the days index very simply and pass values to data attribute

Comment: I have 2 tables employeedetails and leaveapp, so on page_load it reads and shows the emp week-off from table1 on the label and so when applying leave I call the label text to restrict the dates from entering the Mysql table.

Comment: Preventing the value in table is completely irrelevant. I'm asking about your model and the values passed to label. Should be trivial to map those values to day indexes right in your model